# java , eclipse jar problem

Tags: java, eclipse

i'm kind of new to java. I use eclipse and i imported some jar files with some classes by going to properties -> Add External Jars;
The problem is that when i try to use a class from the jar i get the following exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nextapp/echo2/app/event/ActionListener
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
 at Program.main(Program.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nextapp.echo2.app.event.ActionListener
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
 ... 13 more`

The class is supposed to create a window,
i guess that the jar has to import somehow other stuff or something like that,
How can i fix this?

PS. Sorry for the bad code , i don't know tags here.

thansk,
Raxvan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most jars you download will include 0-5 other jars that are needed. They all need included in order to use the jar. Very quickly you end up with 20 jars in a simple 1000 line Java project, but thems are the breaks.

Look inside your downloaded jar zip. Should be a lib directory or such with all the libs you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get around this would be to use a tool like [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to manage downloading dependencies. Depending on what libraries you are using, you may have many transitive dependencies, and doing that all by hand will end up taking a lot of time.